# Show that $T$ is not a linear transformation. $T: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R; T(x)=x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm  currently working on a linear algebra assignment and I need to show that $T$ is not a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}; T(x)= x^2 $

Comment: $T(2+2)=T(4)=16$ but $T(2)+T(2)=4+4=8$. Then, your function $T$ is not linear because $T(2+2)\neq T(2)+T(2)$

Comment: What part of the assignment are you having trouble with? Do you know how to start?

Comment: Well after reading the chapter on linear transformation I can understand that to be called a linear transformation it has to satisfy the following axioms:
 
T1. T(**v** + **v1**)=T(**v**)+T(**v1**) for all **v** and **v1** in V
T2. T(r**v**)= rT(**v**) for all **v** in V and all r in ℝ

I just don't understand how to actually prove that one or both don't hold.

Comment: In this case, proving the negative is fairly easy.  Since the axioms should hold for all values, it is sufficient to find one exception.  This is what the others have done.  They have pointed out some values for which some axioms fail.  If you have another similar problem, try a few particular values in the axioms and see what happens.  If you try a few and they are all correct then you have proved nothing but if just  one fails then you have disproved linearity.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE Taljana, if an answer was useful and solved your main doubts you should mark as the best one (it is an green correct-mark that it is below the up and down marks of the answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k\ne 1$ and $k\ne 0$ then,

$$T(kx)=k^2x^2\ne kT(x)$$

Also, if $x\cdot y \ne 0$, then

$$T(x+y)=(x+y)^2\ne x^2+y^2= T(x)+T(y)$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense I appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

A linear transform requires three things:

1. $T(0)=0$
2. $T(x)+T(y)=T(x+y)$
3. $T(kx)=kT(x)$

$T(x)=x^2$ passes $1$ but not $2$ or $3$ and so is not a linear transform.

Comment: Note that 2 implies 1..

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti; they must have changed the defn since I last looked - I was taught $2T(0)=T(0)$ does not imply $T(0)=0$, although I always thought that it did!

Comment: In an arbitrary vector space $(G,+)$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ (with additive and multiplicative identity $0$ and $1$) you have, for each $g \in G$, $(1+1)g=g$ implies (by the existence of additive inverses in $G$) $(1+1)g-g=g-g=0$, so that by distributivity over the field $(1+1-1)g=0$, i.e., $g=0$.

Comment: I also noted that because there are as many even integers as integers, $\infty=2\infty$ @PaoloLeonetti